# Get Remote Windows Username

Tags: java, spring

I'm developing Java application, based on spring. and i want to get the remote windows username without login on my application.
I saw some ways to do it with JavaScript, but it only works with IE.

Is there a way to do it with spring or Java?

Comment: The remote client would have to send it to you. And even if it does, how do you know it is correct?

Comment: This is a flawed concept, the user name of the remote machine is none of your buisiness (there may not even be a user name). No *sane* browser will expose that to you. If you require authentication, prompt the user to do so.